# How To Attach the tags with the Article in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm using Select 2 in the front end for the multiple tag selection, and I'm using Form model binding to open  the Form. like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('tags','Tags:') !!}
{!! Form::select('tags[]', $tags,null,['id'=>'tag_list', 'class'=>'form-control','multiple']) !!}
```

My Js script part is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$('#tag_list').select2({
    'placeholder':'Choose Tags',
    tags:true,
    tokenSeparators:[",", " "],
    createTag:function(newTag){
        return{
            id:'new:' + newTag.term,
            text:newTag.term + '(new)'
        };
    }
});

</script>
```

And in Controller I'm checking the request and creating new tags if any new tags has been input or attaching the existing selected tags from the database.

```
if ( ! $request->has('tags'))
        {
            $article->tags()->detach();
            return;
        }

        $alltags = array();

        foreach ($request->input('tags') as $tag)
        {
         if (substr($tag, 0, 4) == 'new:')
            {
                $newTag = Tag::create(['name' => substr($tag, 4)]);
                $alltags[] = $newTag->id;
                //dd($newTag);
                continue;
            }

        }
    $article->tags()->attach($alltags);
    $tags = DB::table('tags')->lists('name','tag_id');
    $categories=DB::table('categories')->lists('category_name','category_id');

     return view('admin.pages.edit', compact('article','tags','categories'));
```

Although, it does save all the new tags in the database, it doesn't attach the tags with the article. Rather it throws an exception:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blogs`.`article_tag`, CONSTRAINT `article_tag_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`tag_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `article_tag` (`post_id`, `tag_id`) values (16, ), (16, ), (16, ), (16, ))
```

I've three tables, one article table, another tags and yet another article_tag and using belongsToMany relationship between article and tag. 
I've no idea, how would I be dealing with this problem, Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: dd($alltags) after the foreeach loop to see what you will get in the array. it seems there is nothing in the array

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's returning null. There is nothing in $alltags. What do I need to do, but the new tags are being saved in the database. Since it's blank the attach isn't working.

Comment: it strange it should work. but try using array_push. replace $alltags[] = $newTag->id; with array_push($alltags,$newTag->id);

Comment: It's still Null and dd outputs something like this:
array:3 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => null
]

Comment: dd($newTag) after $newTag = Tag::create(['name' => substr($tag, 4)]); to see what you will get

Comment: Well, it prints only the last tag which I input in the form like this :
#attributes: array:4 [▼
    "name" => "whom"
    "updated_at" => "2016-03-13 13:06:44"
    "created_at" => "2016-03-13 13:06:44"
    "tag_id" => 17
  ]

Comment: instead of dd use \Log::info($newTag); dd will terminate the execution

Comment: It returns the same error as presented in the question with blank values.

Comment: Log::info($newTag); does nothing, and other methods are being executed, but still the same issues with the tag attach.

Comment: I think the ids are not pushed into the array.

Comment: Yes, you were right, it was not pushing the id into array, I think it has to something to do with the id being tweaked with tag_id. Let me

Comment: Comment the continue; and let see what happens

Comment: Yes it prints out the new tags being input, and does save, but the problem is that it attach only the last tag that being selected. $alltags is an array, not sure why it's not attaching all the tags.

Comment: When you log $newTag after the create do you see all the ids you what to attach

Comment: Where can I see the output of Log::info($newTag); ?

Comment: go to storage/logs/laravel.log. clear everything in that file first then try again

Comment: Oh Yes! All fixed by now. thank yo so much for your help. Now both existing tags as well as existing tags are being attached in once. Thank you